# Postfix reject messages *without* attachments?

Tags: postfix

I know this is a bit unusual, but due to circumstances beyond my control, is there anyway to tell postfix to reject messages *without* attachments?  I know how to reject specific attachments, but basically I only want to accept 1 or 2 attachment types, and reject all other messages (including those without any attachments, as those are clearly spam to me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's standard regex, just take what you know and reverse it.

**postfix conf**

```
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
```

**/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks**

```
!/name=[^>]*\.(pdf)/ REJECT
```

**OR**

**/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks**

```
/name=[^>]*\.(pdf)/ ACCEPT
/name=.* REJECT
```

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postfix-block-mime-attachment-files.html